# Comparing hash passwords

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using .net 3.5. The problem here is that I cant seem to get the passwords to match. I have tried using the ComputeHash method on both, but it generates a different hash. As they are now the arrays are different sizes. (Obviously they are based on the same string). What have I done wrong? ("password" is byte[] param by user input)

```
object dataPassword = database.ExecuteScalar("GetUserPassword", new object[] {userName});
if(dataPassword != null && !(dataPassword is DBNull))
{
    SHA1Managed hashProvider = new SHA1Managed();
    byte[] hashedPassword = (byte[])dataPassword;                    
    byte[] hash = hashProvider.ComputeHash(password);
    result = hashedPassword.Equals(hash);

}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't compare a `byte[]` like that. It just compares references. You should use a loop or use `IEnumerable<T>.SequenceEqual` extension method:

```
result = hashedPassword.SequenceEqual(hash);
```

Old way (pre-LINQ):

```
static bool ArrayEquals<T>(T[] first, T[] second) {
    if (first == null && second == null) return true;
    if (first == null || second == null) return false;
    if (first.Length != second.Length) return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < first.Length; ++i)
       if (first[i] != second[i]) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: How do I extend byte so it can use this?

Comment: @JonasB: Can you elaborate on that? Why do you want to extend anything? Since you're on .NET 3.5, just use the SequenceEquals line instead of `result = hashedPassword.Equals(hash);`. Unless you have other problems too, this should solve the issue.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I have double checked the .NET FW version. Checking the intellisense shows no SequenceEquals and I get a compiler error saying it does not exist in the System.Array.

Comment: @JonasB: Do you have `using System.Linq` on top of your source file?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yes, does not compile

Comment: @JonasB: My fault. It's `SequenceEqual` not `SequenceEquals`.

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with encoding. Try using the `UTF8Encoding` class and encoding the string with the `GetBytes` method.

You can also have a look at a set of [hashing classes I made for password verification at Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/blixt/source/browse/trunk/cs/Hashing/).

Answer (score 0):

Print the content of the input of the hash in both cases. I mean to print the byte[], not the strings. If they match, so should the hash. I know nothing about .net but maybe there's a different encoding for the strings, like one using ASCII and another UTF-8?